# How to configure JBoss with its own version of JDK?

Tags: jboss, java

I have a Java web app (WAR) that requires an older (1.5.11) version of the JRE, but am on Linux and spent a good deal of time setting up my environment for 1.6.34.

The web app needs to be hosted locally on JBoss (4.0.4 GA), which I have no experience with. I'm wondering if it is possible to download the 1.5.11 version of the JDK and configure things so that my JBoss instance is the only thing on my system that is using it. This way I don't need to worry about blowing out any of my other configs for 1.6.34.

If it is possible, what are the general steps and what are the JBoss configs I need to make? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Of course this is possible. You can install as many java versions as you like and make sure path/JAVA_HOME is set up correctly for each process you want to launch.
in `JBOSS_HOME/bin/run.conf` you can specify your 1.5 `JAVA_HOME`.

But if you are talking about serious business, you should get somebody (like your software supplier) to upgrade. 1.5.11 is superold and unsupported. and JBoss 4.0.4 is equally old and even less supported.

Comment: JBoss 7.1 this config is JBOSS_HOME/bin/standalone.conf