# How to set java version in JBoss 7?

Tags: java, jboss

I've got machine which is using 2 versions of java(for eg. 6-th and 7-th). If I will run `java -version`, the system will say it's 6-th. Is there an approach to set another java version for JBoss only?

Comment: Check this (Already Answered)
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13570686/how-to-configure-jboss-with-its-own-version-of-jdk

Comment: The runtime to use is configured in the startup shell script. You'll have to modify that to pick a specific runtime you want.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to configure JBoss with its own version of JDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13570686/how-to-configure-jboss-with-its-own-version-of-jdk)

Answer (score 8):

- For `Standalone` server or `localdev`, change file `standalone.conf`
- For `domain control`, change file `domain.conf`

in `$JBOSS_HOME/bin`

### Change the following lines

```
#JAVA_HOME="/opt/java/jdk" → JAVA_HOME="/path/to/jdk"
```

```
#JAVA="" → JAVA="$JAVA_HOME/bin/java"
```

Answer (score 5):

If you start the jboss from standalone.bat (for .sh find the simmilar lines) you can comment the following lines

```
if "x%JAVA_HOME%" == "x" (
  set  JAVA=java
  echo JAVA_HOME is not set. Unexpected results may occur.
  echo Set JAVA_HOME to the directory of your local JDK to avoid this message.
) else (
  set "JAVA=%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java"
)
```

and add

```
set "JAVA=<path to the desired jdk>\bin\java"
```

That worked for me :)

Answer (score 0):

i am using linux and JBoss 7.1.0.

i have both JDK 7 and 8. Version 8 is system default JDK so JBoss 7.1 does not not run on JDK 8. I had to use JDK 7.

i installed JDK 7 in the "/opt/" directory.

Make sure you know the path to your JDK Home, and replace my JDK home with yours.

**Follow these steps:**

1. Open the "Standalone.conf" file found in your JBoss "bin" folder in a text editor.
2. Locate the section below:

> # Specify the location of the Java home directory.  If set then $JAVA will
>
> # be defined to $JAVA_HOME/bin/java, else $JAVA will be "java".
>
> #
>
> #JAVA_HOME="/opt/java/jdk"

3. Edit the last line in the segment above to:

   > JAVA_HOME="/opt/jdk1.7.0_79/"
4. Save the standalone.conf file. YOu are good to go

Answer (score 0):

For `Window` users `@ColithaWa's` answer works

Just edit your `JAVA_HOME` key in the `jboss/bin/standalone.config` and set it to your wherever your new jdk resides.

Answer (score -2):

To Select alternatives for java

As root, type the following command at the shell prompt and you should see something like this:

```
[root@vsr ~]$ /usr/sbin/alternatives --config java
There are 2 programs which provide 'java'.
Selection    Command
-----------------------------------------------
   1           /usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.4.2-gcj/bin/java
*+ 2           /usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.5.0-sun/bin/java
Enter to keep the current selection[+], or type selection number:
```

please refer this link for [more](http://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/docs/Installation_Guide/4/html/Pre_Requisites-Configuring_Your_Java_Environment.html) detail

Comment: But this command will select java version to all the system, isn't it? I need to set another java version to JBoss only.

Comment: This will affect systems and app that use the default jre as this sets the default jre. For a program like JBoss that use jre 7, use its .conf file and not the system wide alternative.